# Jtree inside JScrollPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode myComputer = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("My Computer");
DefaultMutableTreeNode c = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Local Disk(C:)");
DefaultMutableTreeNode vinod = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vinod");
DefaultMutableTreeNode swing = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Swing");
DefaultMutableTreeNode tr = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tree");
DefaultMutableTreeNode a = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("3½ Floppy(A:)");
DefaultMutableTreeNode e = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New Volume(E:)");
c.add(vinod);
vinod.add(swing);
swing.add(tr);
myComputer.add(c);
myComputer.add(a);
myComputer.add(e);


JTree tree = new JTree(myComputer);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
jPanel1.add(scrollPane);
tree.setVisible(true);
```

I got the new tree example from the web, but when I try to show it, it does not appear! I dont know why. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusted the code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), which works fine here

```
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        DefaultMutableTreeNode myComputer = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("My Computer");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode c = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Local Disk(C:)");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode vinod = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vinod");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode swing = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Swing");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode tr = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tree");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode a = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("3½ Floppy(A:)");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode e = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New Volume(E:)");
        c.add(vinod);
        vinod.add(swing);
        swing.add(tr);
        myComputer.add(c);
        myComputer.add(a);
        myComputer.add(e);


        JTree tree = new JTree(myComputer);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        tree.setVisible(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
```

Comment: Ecce potestas [sscce](http://sscce.org/)! @user2712751: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: The problem is that i dont have a frame, im working on an internalframe.

Comment: @user2712751 That shouldn't make any difference. Adjust the SSCCE to work with an internal frame and see whether you can reproduce the problem. If not, look for the differences with your real application

Comment: In the example u add the scrollPane to the ContetPane. I want to add it to a JPanel.